# could not delete file in trash

Tags: linux, debian, delete, trash

I have a file named "1" maybe it was created by using the wrong command when using redirect.

Such as:

```bash
commond 2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

When I try to empty the trash, the file named "1" is unable to delete.

[image]

I have tried to delete the folder `/home/$USER/.local/share/Trash`, but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: According to the screenshot, the file is not in `/home/...`, but rather in `/media/...`. What is the output of the command `namei -l /media/$USER/Data/.Trash-1000/files/1`?

Comment: Thank you very much. This problem was solved by deleting the files under/media/$USER/Data/. Trash-1000 and reseating the Portable storage device.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in the terminal, it should delete the file.

```
cd ~/.local/share/Trash # ~ stands for /home/user. just copy-paste.
sudo rm 1
```